# Is there anyway to pull comments from buzz?

Tags: php, google-buzz

Is there a way to get the comments from buzz right now? I understand that the API is not fully out but i was wondering if anyone found a way to get comments from buzz.

Please notice that i am talking about comments and (NOT) status messages.

(Example, i publish something on buzz, 10 people comment on it, i don't want to get the buzz status message only but i want to the 10 comments other people had on my status message)

If you need more explanations please tell me and i will edit the post

(this is clearly not a homework)

Comment: You'll have to wait for the API to be finalized or use something to parse the HTML (Not Regex!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an RSS feed for the comments for each status update.  On an individual status update, click the down arrow and select "Link to this post".  Then click the orange RSS icon in the browsers address bar.  Or, if you know the post id and user id, plug it into here - http://buzz.googleapis.com/feeds/{user id}/comments/{post id}.  That is the RSS feed for the comments for that update.  Parse the feed in PHP or any other language and there you go.

For a little more automation, take the main RSS feed for the user (http://buzz.googleapis.com/feeds/{user id}/public/posted), then you can parse out the post id for each post and build the comments feed url from that (http://buzz.googleapis.com/feeds/{user id}/comments/{post id}).

Answer (score 1):

This capability is documented here: http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#activity-comments

Basically you make an HTTP request for: https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/activities/userId/@self/activityId/@comments